# Ошибка при делении BigDecimal

Tags: java

Написал код, в котором должны выполняться арифметические операции. Всё работает правильно кроме деления...
Выбрасывает такое exception, если делить меньшее число на большее:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1690)
at math_action_realization.GoMath.getResultMath(GoMath.java:30)
at math_action_realization.RunTet.main(RunTet.java:12
```

Так выглядит код:

```
public class GoMath
{
    public <T extends Number> T getResultMath(T arg1, T arg2, String op)
    {
        BigDecimal bigArg1 = new BigDecimal(arg1 instanceof Integer ? arg1.intValue(): arg1.doubleValue());
        BigDecimal bigArg2 = new BigDecimal(arg2 instanceof Integer ? arg2.intValue() : arg2.doubleValue());
        BigDecimal bigRes = null;
        switch (op) {
            case "/": {
                if (arg1.intValue() == 0 || arg2.intValue() == 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        throw  new DivZeroException("Неможливе ділення на 0");
                    }
                    catch (DivZeroException dz)
                    {
                        System.out.print(dz.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                bigRes = bigArg1.divide(bigArg2);
                break;
            }
            case "*": {
                bigRes = bigArg1.multiply(bigArg2);
                break;
            }
            case "+": {
                bigRes = bigArg1.add(bigArg2);
                break;
            }
            case "-": {
                bigRes = bigArg1.subtract(bigArg2);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(arg1 instanceof Integer && arg2 instanceof Integer)
        {
            return (T) new Integer(bigRes.intValue());
        }
        if(arg1 instanceof Integer && arg2 instanceof Integer && arg1.intValue() < arg2.intValue() && op.equals("/"))
        {
            return (T) new Double(bigRes.doubleValue());
        }

        return (T) new Double(bigRes.doubleValue());

    }

}
```

Вызываю в main:

```
public class RunTet
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Number a = 6, b = 7;

       GoMath gm = new GoMath();
       System.out.print(gm.getResultMath(a, b, "/"));



    }
}
```

Comment: Лучше текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос в текстовом виде, чтобы потом, люди с подобной ошибкой, смогли найти его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё, как я писал в ответе на прошлый вопрос, можете применить `Double` вместо `BigDecimal` (у которого нет таких заморочек). Думал сами догадаетесь.

```
double dblArg1 = arg1.doubleValue();
double dblArg2 = ...
Double dblRes;
switch(op) {
    ...
    case "/": dblRes = dblArg1 / dblArg2;
    ...
}
if (arg1 instanceof Integer) return new Integer(dblRes.intValue());
return dblRes;
```

Comment: Нужно избавляться от Double везде, где требуется точность.

Answer (score 9):

При делении BigDecimals указывайте способ округления в методе .divide(...). В противном случае можно получить ArithmeticException, если нет точного округлённого результирующего значения, например, 1/3. Таким образом, всегда следует делать так:

```
a = b.divide(c, decimals, rounding);
```

Comment: теперь оно всегда делает его double. Можно ли чтоб возвращало число того типа, который получился в результате деления ?

Comment: В любом случае получается double, точнее. дробное число. Просто в данном случае получилась бесконечная дробная часть, что привело к ошибке, и этот факт вылез наружу. bigRes.intValue() в return отбросит ненужную дробную часть. При делении малого целого на большее целое получите в результате как положено целый 0.

Comment: @Sergey, мне просто нужно чтобы если при делении получается дробное число - возвращало дробное, если целое - соответственно!!!

Comment: @Vitaliy Представляет ли double целое число можно проверить так `(dlb % 1) == 0`

Comment: @Vitaliy А BigDecimal так `db.remainder(BigDecimal.ONE).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0`

Comment: @Sergey, большое спасибо !!!!